# Display total received data (from network history in System Monitor) in the Unity Panel

Tags: unity, indicator, panel, notification-area, bandwidth

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. Is there a way to display the total received data which is available in the network history of System monitor tool, on the Unity Panel?

I have limited amount of bandwidth available every month, so it would be nice to have that status visible all the time.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? 16.04? 14.04? This might affect what software is available/compatible for your system

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself

Installed [indicator-sysmonitor](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/ubuntu-appindicator-that-displays-bash.html).

Then added this command to get total received:

```
ifconfig wlp3s0 | grep -oP 'RX bytes:\s*\K\d+' | awk '{ printf("%.0f\n", $0 / 1024 / 1024)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer is great for listing network traffic received for the current boot but this means manual book keeping to track against the ISP's monthly billing cycle.

A better method is to use `vnstat`. See: [How to track the total network data in a month](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15836/how-to-track-the-total-network-data-in-a-month/844317#844317)

You can use `conky` to display your monthly consumption on your desktop, along with the current session totals that you see using `indicator-systmonitor` now:

[image: conky vnstat]

To learn how to setup `vnstat` follow the link above.